# If bitcoincore.org goes down how can I access it? What can I do to help others access it?

Tags: bitcoin-core, censorship-resistance

[bitcoincore.org](https://bitcoincore.org/) is a trusted resource for information on new Bitcoin Core releases and soft fork upgrades. How do I access it if it is taken offline? How can I help others access it if it is taken offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wladimir van der Laan answered this on [Mastodon](https://x0f.org/@orionwl/105592668865478682).

> if you want to help, make mirrors (can we do something like "deterministic verifiable builds for websites"?), host the files, seed the torrents

Is there a more robust way to create a mirror exist now, other than `wget -mkxKE -e robots=off https://bitcoincore.org`?

> Yes wget seems suboptimal. The robust way is to clone the website off github (git@github.com:bitcoin-core/bitcoincore.org.git), so that you have a copy of the source code as well, then you can build it yourself. That gets *all* releases and verifies them against their gitian.sigs hashes
>
> However that's for the website—it won't give you a copy of the historical release binaries, i'm not sure of a good way to mirror those, maybe best would be to make a script based on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/get_previous_releases.py and https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoin-maintainer-tools/blob/master/gitian-verify.py
>
> This one might actually be best, it downloads SHA256SUMS.asc for an arbitrary release, verifies the signature, and downloads all the files mentioned in it: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/verifybinaries